# How to solve bad numeric value error for git commit?

Tags: python-3.x

If I want to commit my code with `git commit -m "Initialize commit"` I'll get this error:

```
getting fatal:  bad numeric config value 'true_' for 'color.ui': invalid unit
```

How can I solve it?
What does `color.ui` error means in git?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Problem is that Git can't do anything with `_true` as a value for `color.ui`.

This should be fixed with by editing your git config via `git config --global color.ui always`.

**Edit**: Documentation for `color.ui`:

> This variable determines the default value for variables such as
> color.diff and color.grep that control the use of color per command
> family. Its scope will expand as more commands learn configuration to
> set a default for the --color option. Set it to false or never if you
> prefer Git commands not to use color unless enabled explicitly with
> some other configuration or the --color option. Set it to always if
> you want all output not intended for machine consumption to use color,
> to true or auto (this is the default since Git 1.8.4) if you want such
> output to use color when written to the terminal.